# Flutter - Column MainAxisAlignment spaceBetween doesn't work inside Row

Tags: flutter

Good day.
I am trying to build a UI where the widget tree is like Row -> children(Column, List). The problem is I want my column to take the same height as the List. It is not happening. I am including screenshots and my code here. Any kind of help is appreciable

[image: The UI]

You can see that the column on the left is not taking all the space and space between the time and expanding more icons is not working either.

I am including my code here.

```
class CollapsibleAgendaList extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final SessionListCubit cubit = context.read<SessionListCubit>();

    return ListView.separated(
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {
                    print('Tapped on time section. ');
                  },
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: [
                        Text('10:30 Am'),
                        Icon(Icons.expand_more),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: ListView.separated(
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      print("item  builder.");
                      return CollapsibleAgendaItem(
                          session: cubit.state.sessions[index], isLiked: true);
                    },
                    separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return const Divider(
                        color: Colors.grey,
                      );
                    },
                    itemCount: 2),
              ),
            ],
          );
        },
        separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
          return const Divider(
            color: Colors.grey,
          );
        },
        itemCount: 4);
  }
}
```

Edit: I'm going to explain the reason for this problem in my case. Maybe it will help someone in the future. When Flutter builds the `child` it asks for the required width/height from the `parent`. But as I used a `ListView` as a child, it doesn't know the `height` instantly. So, the `Column` was taking only the `height` it needed. But, I experimented that providing a `height` for the `ListView` solve the problem. But, In my case, I can't determine the `height` in runtime, instead, I used a `Column` like the accepted answer, which solved my problem. In the future, If someone finds a solution with `ListView`, Please do comment here.

Comment: does `CollapsibleAgendaItem` have fixed height

Comment: No. I don't know the height because of the list view, the number of data can be any number.

Comment: cant see grey part, are you trying to fit the height for left part?

Comment: Yes. I want the left part to take the full height like right part.

Comment: try using `IntrinsicHeight` as I've posted

Comment: Glad to help, you can check the attached link for more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can top `Row` with [`IntrinsicHeight`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/IntrinsicHeight-class.html)(expensive-widget). Also while you are not using scrollable physics, you can replace listVIew with Column

```dart
return ListView.separated(
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      return IntrinsicHeight(
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            ColoredBox(
              color: Colors.red,
              child: GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                  print('Tapped on time section. ');
                },
                child: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: [
                      Text('10:30 Am'),
                      Icon(Icons.expand_more),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Column(
              children: List.generate(2, (index) {
                return Column(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      height: 200,
                    ),
                    const Divider(
                      color: Colors.grey,
                    ),
                  ],
                );
              }),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );
    },
    separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
      return const Divider(
        color: Colors.grey,
      );
    },
    itemCount: 4);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `mainAxisSize:MainAxisSize.max` inside column.

Comment: I will check noe and let you know

Comment: It doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

To make the contents of the Row fill the entire height, you need to set  `crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,` on the Row.

Here is the documentation on [CrossAxisAlignment vs MainAxisAlignment](https://docs.flutter.dev/codelabs/layout-basics#crossaxisalignment-property).

> CrossAxisAlignment.stretch
> Stretches children across the cross axis. (Top-to-bottom for Row, left-to-right for Column)

Comment: It doesn't work. Give the error 'BoxConstraints forces an infinite height.'.